# Limit the number of @Asynchronous requests to a specifc EJB in WebLogic?

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.1

I have Stateless EJB (3.1) deployed in WebLogic 12. One of the methods is marked @Asynchronous.

Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent asynchronous requests to this bean? I would expect that you could someone limit the size of the thread pool on a per-bean basis, and then excessive requests would wait for previous requests to complete.

** For a variety of reasons, I believe it would be a bad idea to actually do this to anything other than a bean that is only ever deployed once, which cannot be guaranteed. So I don't think I actually want to use the solution. But I've done so much research at this point, that I just want to know how it is properly done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EJB instances are pooled, and not the methods. So if you configure in your AS to have a maximum amount of 5 instances of your particular EJB running, you won't have more than 5 concurrent requests running (even if they are asynchronous and a client already sends a new request), other requests will be waiting.